# PHP SOAP Service - Uploading file larger than 15MB fails

Tags: php, soap

Is there anything that would be preventing a `PHP SOAP Service` from uploading a file larger than about 15MB? Smaller files work great, but larger ones fail without any noticeable errors.

Settings that I might need to change? Nothing in the apache logs.

Comment: Heh, if the WS is made to serve certain data from a basic service (a stored procedure, a file, etc), if the source is too big, the message is too big and it will be a timeout in the client. Filter output on the service by requiring params from the client

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini to a value higher than 15MB.  For example:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

Comment: Yeah, those are both set to 50MB.

Comment: Have you changed them recently? If so, have you restarted Apache?

Comment: Yes, changed them years ago, and apache has been restarted since then.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging? I'd use something like: `$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 1));`